# Firefox and safari can't create fetch request of 'CORS' mode

Tags: javascript, firefox, request, cors, fetch

My app is work perfectly in chrome when i try to create a cross origin request.
but in firefox i get following error:

> 'mode' member of RequestInit 'CORS' is not a valid value for
>   enumeration RequestMode.

i create my request header like following:

```
    this.requestParameter = {

        method: this.config.method,
        mode: 'CORS',
        headers: new Headers(headerConfig)
    }

    this.request = new Request(url,this.requestParameter);
```

how can i solve this problem in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

just change your request mode to `'cors'` mean lower case the word as following:

```
this.requestParameter = {

    method: this.config.method,
    mode: 'cors', //change this
    headers: new Headers(headerConfig)
}

this.request = new Request(url,this.requestParameter);
```